# 14.10 built-in preview files and folders

Tags: nautilus, 14.10, previews

I was wondering how to get a preview of files and came across the programs `gnome-sushi` and `gloobus-preview`. However, in the official Ubuntu 14.10 Documentation, it seems like this should work out of the box, but it doesn't. If I click the space bar in nautilus nothing happens.

Link to documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-preview.html

Is this a known issue or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gnome-sushi` should work out of the box. You might need to reboot, or restart nautilus. Like so: `nautilus -q`.

If that still doesn't work, try reinstalling it: `sudo apt-get purge gnome-sushi` and install it again: `sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi`. Restart `nautilus -q`. This should work.

For gloobus, when installed with the webup8 ppa, like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview
```

It should be noted that you need extra dependencies to get it fully functional and to integrate it better with your file manager of choice. (nemo, nautilus)

This is for previewing documents a little better, although it is not optimal:

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv gnumeric
```

And the second is to integrate gloobus with either nautilus or nemo:

If you have `nautilus`:

```
sudo apt-get install gloobus-sushi
```

Or if you have `nemo`:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-gloobus-sushi
```

Both applications needs to be restart before continuing: `nemo -q` / `nautilus -q`

Reference:

- [Quick File Previewer `Gloobus Preview` Updated To Work With Ubuntu 14.04 And 14.10 / Linux Mint 17 And 17.1 ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/quick-file-previewer-gloobus-preview.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply, gnome-sushi obviously works. But it didn't work out of the box, I tried restarting and rebooting, nothing changed. This is very confusing as this is stated in the official doc

Comment: i needed to do a full install of gnome-sushi, maybe this is because i upgraded from 14.04? However it works now so I'll mark this ans answer.